# Why is the do - while only accepting pLife condition?

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

The only way the loop works is when the player runs out of lifes.  The game is supposed to allow the player to answer math questions, they answer until either they, or the magician runs out of lives.  So int the do while loop, the while is only working once pLife runs out, and completely ignores eLife, why is that?

```
do 
{
    int Number = rand() % 20 + 1;       //Desides the random number that will be used in the program
    int aNumber = rand() % 20 + 1;
    int rng = rand() % 3 + 1;
    cout <<"Player Life Total = " <<pLife <<endl;
    cout <<"Mathmagican Life Total = " <<eLife <<endl;

    if (rng == 1)
    {
        cout <<"What is " <<Number <<"X" << aNumber <<"?\n\n";
        cin >> answer;
            if (answer == Number * aNumber)
            {
                cout <<"What!!! How is that possible you deflected my attack!\n\n";
                cout <<"Ahh it hit me!! you hit me with my own magic! Thats not fair!\n\n";
                eLife = eLife- 1;
            }
            else if (answer > Number * aNumber, answer < Number * aNumber)
            {
                cout <<"I told you that you couldn't defeat me!\n\n";
                cout <<"Now die!";
                pLife = pLife - 1;
            }
    }
    else if (rng == 2)
    {
        cout <<"What is " <<Number <<"-" << aNumber <<"?\n\n";
        cin >> answer;
            if (answer == Number - aNumber)
            {
                cout <<"What!!! How is that possible you deflected my attack!\n\n";
                cout <<"Ahh it hit me!! you hit me with my own magic! Thats not fair!\n\n";
                eLife = eLife- 1;
            }
            else if (answer > Number - aNumber, answer < Number - aNumber)
            {
                cout <<"I told you that you couldn't defeat me!\n\n";
                cout <<"Now die!";
                pLife = pLife - 1;
            }
    }
    else if (rng == 3)
    {
        cout <<"What is " <<Number <<"+" << aNumber <<"?\n\n";
        cin >> answer;
            if (answer == Number + aNumber)
            {
                cout <<"What!!! How is that possible you deflected my attack!\n\n";
                cout <<"Ahh it hit me!! you hit me with my own magic! Thats not fair!\n\n";
                eLife = eLife- 1;
            }
            else if (answer > Number + aNumber, answer < Number + aNumber)
            {
                cout <<"I told you that you couldn't defeat me!\n\n";
                cout <<"Now die!";
                pLife = pLife - 1;
            }
    }
}while (eLife > 0, pLife > 0);  

    if (eLife == 0)
    {
        cout <<"Oh no! I cant belive it... you... actualy... defeated me?!\n\n";
        cout <<"NO!!! CURSE YOU!!!";
        cout <<"You've Won!\n\n";
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pLife == 0)
    {
        cout <<"MWAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!! I told you i would win!\n\n";
        cout <<"Game over";
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

}

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator for reference

Answer (score 2):

Each of the individual expressions in comma-separated expressions will be evaluated and their side effects will take place. However, the value of an entire comma-separated expression is only the result of the *rightmost expression.* Thus, the while condition evaluates as true only if `pLife > 0` returns true.

To correct the problem, change it to a single expression using boolean operators such as `&&` or `||`

Comment: Tried, and nothing happened, it is still the same result.

Comment: Well, what is your new boolean expression?  The usual methods of troubleshooting now apply.